# Para usar o Admob é obrigatório publicar o app em loja oficial?

Tags: android, admob

Estou terminando um aplicativo que apresenta banners vindos do Admob. Não ficou claro (para mim) se o aplicativo tem que ser, obrigatoriamente, distribuído numa loja oficial (Google Play ou Apple App Store), ou se posso distribuir por outros meios, como email, website, etc.

Comment: Não, não precisa publicar na loja oficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é obrigatório sua aplicação estar na loja do Google para que seja monetizada, no entanto você [tem que assinar](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html?hl=pt-br) seu APK e não distribuir em modo de depuração. Caso você publique em modo de depuração, este mesmo é considerado que está em teste. De acordo com as [políticas do **AdMob**](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=pt-br):

> É contra a política da AdMob clicar nos próprios anúncios ativos.
>   Durante o desenvolvimento e os testes, use anúncios de teste. Se você
>   não precisa renderizar anúncios ativos antes do lançamento, evite
>   clicar neles. Se você clicar em anúncios ativos, sua conta na AdMob
>   poderá ser suspensa.

Para saber mais detalhes veja [na documentação](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-br) e também conferir as [Políticas da AdMob e do Google AdSense](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128543?hl=pt-BR&ref_topic=2745287&visit_id=1-636207119070273006-684889200&rd=1).

**Observação**: Verifique o `ID` do anúncio, caso não esteja inserido corretamente, você não será monetizado.